# Electric current in a plate

Tags: electromagnetism

There is a metal plate with an arbitrary shape. At one point of the plate, say A, we introduce DC current $I$, which leaves the plate at another point, say B. How would you determine the current density in the whole object? (This is not a homework)

Comment: Hi wawa. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: I would use finite elements.

Comment: Adding "This is not a homework." is unlikely to get the question reopened. It would be more helpful to clarify the question and explain how you've tried to answer the question yourself.  When you say a "metal plate with an arbitrary shape", do you mean a uniform thickness thin sheet with an arbitrary two-dimensional outline?    Are you asking about what are the possible theoretical or experimental methods to "determine" the current density?  Have you heard of Laplace's Equation?  Do you know the boundary conditions for electric field at the surface/edge of a conductor?